# Equivalent of Microsoft Paint's eraser in Adobe Acrobat Pro

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat

Is there any equivalent of Microsoft Paint's eraser in Adobe Acrobat Pro?

I am aware that I can use the redaction feature or delete object, but I wonder if there is any more direct way to delete part of a PDF, without having to do it by rectangles (redaction) or by objects.

I use Adobe Acrobat Pro XI with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, PDF is not a raster image per definition. It may have pages consisting only of raster files, such as scanned documents, but this is just one case of PDF. Per definition, PDF is a selection of various objects.

Second, PDF can be edited to some extent, but for serious editing, you better go to the original files.

In the Preferences, the Content Editing tab, you can specify helper applications for editing images (Image Editor… button) and for editing pages and objects (Pages/Object Editor… button). A good combination is Photoshop for (raster) images and Illustrator for pages and objects.

Comment: Thanks. Sure, PDF is not raster, but I was hoping it could modify the objects to imitate Microsoft Paint's eraser.

Comment: I am not aware of such a tool for vector objects, but I may be wrong…