# Selecting several objects in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro by drag and drop

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat

Short version: Is it possible to several objects in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro by drag and drop?

---

Example: I would like to move all the objects present in the selected area below (the selected area is in light blue):

[image]

I could select all of them with `Content Editing > Edit Text & Images` on, then clicking each object while pressing on <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, but it's tedious when there are many objects (in the example they are actually over 100 objects in the selected area).

I use Adobe Acrobat XI Pro with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: See answer to http://superuser.com/questions/863159/equivalent-of-microsoft-paints-eraser-in-adobe-acrobat-pro .

Comment: @MaxWyss Thanks for the pointer, but I don't see which part of the answer you pointed to answers this question :/

Comment: The reference to external editors which are more powerful.

Comment: @MaxWyss Are any other suitable tools vectorial?

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere, I do have good experience using Illustrator.

Answer (score -1):

hold down alt while dragging selection window out with Left mouse button